# output binary value as BCD / decimal

Tags: assembly, pic

Currently trying to convert a PIC assembler program which reads incoming characters (0-9, A-F) and outputs that value on PORTA (on some LED's). This works fine for a 'binary format' output.

```
MOVF RCREG,W    ;Move the received byte to W
    MOVWF TMP_TX    ;Move W to TPM_TX
    movwf TEMP      ;Move W to TEMP
    btfsc TEMP,6    ;Start 4bit convert - bit 6 is set for both A-F and a-f
    addlw -7        ;subtract 7 to map 'A' as 10 thru 'F' as 15
    andlw 0xf       ;mask down to nibble. Result is 0x0 - 0xF
    MOVWF PORTA     ;Move W to PORTA
```

I need the output to be 'decimal', that is set PORTA,0 when 1 is read, PORTA,3 (only) when 4 is read etc. I have looked at some BCD / decimal conversion code and of course I can iterate through w (case statements) to see what it contains and then set the port accordingly but I wondered if there was an easier way.

PIC16F628A, MPLABX

Regards
Active

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "decimal" output, your current code is probably (I don't know PIC assembly, so I'm guessing a bit) taking ASCII character and turning it to value 0-15 (where digits 0-9 and letters A-F map to values 0-15 like hexadecimal digit would). So if you enter just 0-9 letters, it will convert that only to 0-9 values. If you want particular output value, you can create look-up-table defining 16 values, and use current result 0-15 to index into that LUT, fetching the new value to output (if the value can't be calculated by some formula easily). That's like `case`.

Comment: Am I missing something here, or do you just want to map the ASCII values `'1' .. '9'` to integer values `0..8`?  If so, obviously you should simply subtract `'1'` (which has ASCII code 49 decimal, 0x31).

Comment: The current output is currently 'binary' (for an incoming 3 PORTA,0 and 1 are set), I need all the outputs to be 1 LED on only, i.e. incoming 3 results in only PORTA, 2 being set. I was hoping to find something 'easier' than a lookup table / case statement.

Comment: i.e. for the value 0-15 from the letter conversion you want to end with value [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, ...] (if you have only 8 LEDs, then the letter "8"  will be the last eight LED on (128), for input "0" no LED will be on). You can do that by testing zero separately, and then loading value 1 into some register, and shift it left N-1 times. If the PIC instruction set is limited to shift-by-1 or immediate only, you would have a loop, at that point it's better to use LUT performance wise (if you don't need to save memory space). I.e. in C: `PORTA = (1<<(input-'1'));`

Comment: For those confused about what the existing code does, it looks like it takes a hex character i.e. `0` .. `9`, `A` ... `F`, `a` ... `f` and converts it to the equivalent 4 bit binary number e.g. `0x31` => `0x01`, `0x41` => `0x0a`

Comment: There is no alternative but to convert to bcd, (optionally) stripping out the leading zeroes and convert each nibble to ascii using simple addition.

Comment: How about a computed goto?  It will take up a bit of memory but it is a fast direct technique.